# DelegateCall to internal function doesn't store variable

Tags: delegatecall

Why isn't delegate call able to run internal functions?

What is the difference between a self directed delegate call and a contract normally calling one of it's internal function?

```js
contract DelegateInternal {

    address public senderOne;
    address public senderTwo;

    function dellyCall() payable returns(uint256) {
        senderOne = msg.sender;
        this.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3('otherFunction()')));
    }

    // Not able to set this variable when this function is made internal
    function otherFunction()
    internal {
           senderTwo = msg.sender;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is internal. That means there's no way to call it directly through a message call, since the signature (`bytes4(sha3('otherFunction()'))` in this case) isn't in the table of functions. If you must do this, you have to expose a public function, which you can also limit to self-calls if needed by doing `require(msg.sender == address(this))`.